# Input type date and input type time have broken UI in firefox

Tags: html, date, firefox, input, time

I was making a form in angular that contains input `type=date` and input `type=time`, the UI works good in chrome and chromium but it's broken in firefox, is there something can be done to fix that?

by broken UI I mean the icons are not there and the dropdown of the time picker not there too.

**firefox:**

[image]

**chrome:**

[image]

Comment: Every browser has its own UI for inputs of type date, number, ... and some other browsers doesn't have at all. if you need sophisticated calendar controls you need to use one like [angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker)